# Check if the user is logged in Flutter & firebase auth |

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm using firebase authentication to authenticate users in my Flutter app ,when the user entered his right password the app shows him the home page normally but when the password is wrong doesn't happened nothing, I want to show an alert every time the user enters a wrong password, How can I do this?

Comment: Check if the current user is `!= null`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you write all the code please

Comment: write your code so we can know what you are using

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [`currentUser()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html) method:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
    // signed in
} else {
   // signed out   
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, probably as currentUser returns a future, which is not null and would always make the app think the user is signed in. With await or .then can actually get the user object and not the future.

Comment: this answer is not correct FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() is async in firebase_auth plugin 0.11.0, perhaps in the past it was synchronous

Comment: You can always use ```if (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() == null)```

Comment: nullsafety issue... `error: The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'`

Comment: This is now a getter, so drop the `()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

Answer (score 14):

That didn't work for me so this is what I did:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((firebaseUser){
  if(firebaseUser == null)
   {
     //signed out
   }
   else{
    //signed in
  }
});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Firebase user is always valid even when it's being deleted.

Comment: @OliverDixon I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the shortest and safest answer is:

```
if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid == null){
// not logged
} else {
// logged
}
```

It gets the User ID (if exists) which is recorded on Firebase Authentication UID field for each user have been authenticated on the app before, otherwise it returns null.
 The question mark in `currentUser?.uid` is a Null safety to avoid null exception (returns null if null).

Answer (score 3):

try this, it worked for me.

Get token from user and refresh it.

```
Future<bool> isUserLogged() async {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await getLoggedFirebaseUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        IdTokenResult tokenResult = await firebaseUser.getIdToken(refresh: true);
        return tokenResult.token != null;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Future<FirebaseUser> getLoggedFirebaseUser() {
    return firebaseAuthInstance().currentUser();
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Home(),
    );
} else {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Welcome(),
    );
}
```

Comment: Please avoid putting code alone as answer and try explain how it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

void _emailLogin() async{
final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

```
    if(user != null){
     // Do something
    }
  } catch (e) {

    String exception = Auth.getExceptionText(e);
    Flushbar(
      title: "Sign In Error",
      message: exception,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..show(context);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Init Method Do This..**

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((firebaseUser) {
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
     
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()));
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()));
    }
  });
```