# Flutter - Trying to build a future context to check if user is logged in, but my build method has an error

Tags: firebase, flutter

Fairly newish to flutter, and I have an app that can succesfully log into Firebase.  However now I'm trying to make it so the app skips the registration page if the user is already registered.  I started a new template for this post.

I used this post: [How to correctly check if a user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463574/flutter-how-to-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in-if-so-show-other-screen) for the inspiration, but mine seems to throw an error.  I'm using VSCODE if that makes a difference:

```
import 'package:buildfuture/FirstPage.dart';
import 'package:buildfuture/SecondPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp implements StatelessWidget {

  @override 
    Widget build() {
      return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>( 
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
            return First();
          }
           return Second();
          }
      );
    }
}
```

I don't understand the error:

> 'Object.toString' ('String Function()') isn't a valid override of
>   'Diagnosticable.toString' ('String Function({DiagnosticLevel
>   minLevel})').

and

> 'MyApp.build' ('Widget Function()') isn't a valid override of
>   'StatelessWidget.build' ('Widget Function(BuildContext)').

Just in case I've also included FirstPage.dart.  SecondPage.dart is exactly the same except the class is named Second

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class First extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Container(
      child: new Center(
        child: new Icon(Icons.accessibility_new, size: 150.0, color: Colors.brown)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is the line `class MyApp implements StatelessWidget`

You should use `extends` keyword instead `implements`.

Try:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{ // your class body ... }
```

and also `build` method signature must include a `BuildContext` parameter.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){ return ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos.  I assumed since your other example didn't include the BuildContext parameter and it was included only as part of the future build, that was all tha was required.  Fixed now.

Comment: @vwdewaal Ohh... that was my fault. Sorry about it! 
thanks too.

Answer (score 1):

> 'MyApp.build' ('Widget Function()') isn't a valid override of 'StatelessWidget.build' ('Widget Function(BuildContext)').

Bad `override` signature.

Your build() method into MyApp class must to be build(BuildContext context):

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>( 
    future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
        return First();
      }
       return Second();
      }
  );
}
```

If you place a breakpoint at line `FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;` what is the value of `snapshot.data` ?

Answer (score 0):

sigh.

I didn't see... in my original code I "implement" rather than "extend". It's been killing me for 2 days.