# check authentication state of User using FirebaseAuth in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, stream

I know a question like this exists but it is filled with outdated and incorrect answers. The new [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) docs use Streams to get the state of the User and I had a hard time, trying to perform such a trivial task because I am inexperienced with Flutter and Dart. Here is the answer and ref of the outdated question.

- Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714618/14080391
- Ref: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state

I am expecting an answer along with StreamBuilder, and here is the code I have written up till now:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) { 
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          print("data exists");
          return snapshot.data ? First() : SignIn();
        }
        else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
      future: isUserLoggedIn(),
    );
  }

Stream<bool> isUserLoggedIn() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
        // return false; ???
      } else {
        print('User is signed in!');
        // return true; ???
      }
    });
  }
```

EDIT:

> Firebase Auth enables you to subscribe in realtime to this state via a >Stream. Once called, the stream provides an immediate event of the user's >current authentication state, and then provides subsequent events whenever ?the authentication state changes.

[FlutterFire Auth Doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state)

Comment: `StreamBuilder` does not accept a `future` property, it expects a `stream` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`isUserLoggedIn()` isn't returning a stream of any kind. I recommend just listening to the actual `authStateChanges()` stream.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) { 
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          print("data exists");
          return First();
        }
        else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: the code I have written in the question is outdated.

Comment: I was asking for the updated code as a way for more rookie developers to not stumble upon the previous thread with incorrect and outdated answers. The answer which you have given is correct!

Comment: This seems to work in Android, but for Web the `hasData` never triggers

Comment: @Benjamin - in my case, "FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges" stream gives me event for login & logout, but not for create account. - is there anything, needs to specify?