# main() function is refreshed in flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I check user login state by `FirebaseAuth` and depending on this state, I navigate user to each screen.

```
      home: MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context)
            .copyWith(textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(1.0)),
        child: initialLoginState.value
            ? const MainNavigationScreen(tab: "일기")
            : const SignUpScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final initialLoginState =
    ValueNotifier<bool>(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null);
```

when app is firstly opened, if user is not signed in FirebaseAuth, it navigates to `SignUpScreen`.

And user proceed `phone auth` verification.

```
  void _verifyPhoneFireAuth() async {
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final authPhoneNumber = "+82 10${_selectedPhone.toString().substring(4)}";
    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: authPhoneNumber,
      timeout: const Duration(
        seconds: 60,
      ),
      verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {
        await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).then(
          (value) {
            _timer.cancel();

   
          },
        ).catchError(
          (e) {
            _timer.cancel();

            setState(() {
              _requestPhoneAuthSms = false;
            });
          },
        );
      },
      verificationFailed: (error) {
        if (error.code == "invalid-phone-number") {
          showErrorSnackBar(context, "잘못된 휴대폰 번호입니다.");
        }
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
        setState(() {
          _verificationId = verificationId;
        });
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
    );
  }
```

After proceeding phone authentication step, user still needs to write name, gender, extra information and moves to second sign up screen to fill up information like region.

However the problem is when user proceeds phone auth, it creates user account on fire auth, sometimes it moves to `MainNavigationScreen(tab: "일기")` led by `main()` function.

I guess main function is called, and at that time, user's login state is changed, so it is reflected.

I don't know my guess is correct or not and how to block this this happen.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you detect the initial login state with:

```
final initialLoginState =
    ValueNotifier<bool>(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null);
```

This code is correct to detect the currently signed in user, but when the app starts up the Firebase SDK restores the previously signed in user from local storage and this takes some time (as it needs to call to the server to a.o. check if the account has been disabled since it was last active). While that is happening, the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is `null` and *that* is what your code picks up and acts on.

To properly detect the initial login state, you should use an auth state listener as shown in the documentation on [getting the currently logged in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      print(user.uid);
    }
  });
```

If you attach such a listener at startup, the first time your code gets called is after the SDK has restored the user credentials from local storage, so you'll never see the initial `null` value that you now have.

The typical way to implement this in a UI is to use the `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` in a `StreamBuilder`, as for example shown in this answer: [check authentication state of User using FirebaseAuth in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669262/check-authentication-state-of-user-using-firebaseauth-in-flutter/63669530#63669530).